# An English equivalent of "還真是抬舉他了"?

Tags: translation

I understand what it means, ([I] really overpraised him or something), but I can't figure out a good english translation of it.

It has the meaning of "overlooking" or "looked up" or something, but I can't find the correct word.

Comment: 这是查词典的问题，it is a matter of looking up 抬举 in a dictionary ，e。g。iciba says：praise or promote sb. to show favour sb.
also see at least １０ sample sentences。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a kind of ironic meaning.

How about  'You're overdoing the praise a bit there, aren't you?'

Answer (score 2):

An acceptable translation will be "(You) overestimated him/her".

Comment: iciba and other dictionaries are wrong then？it seems ＂over estimate＂ does not exist， ＂overestimate＂ does exist， but does not agree with how dictionaries  translate （真）抬举，and it is not just iciba which does not have ＂overestimate＂ as possible translation： 小马词典：to praise; to promote (as a favour)，Line Dictionary，dict。cn： favour。
overestimating sb。can result in 抬举 the person，
but the two activities are not the same， overestimate：对…作过高的评价； ，对…估计过高

Comment: @S.Rhee I fixed my typo. :D

Comment: regarding the difference between ＂praising sb。＂ and ＂overestimating sb。＂，neither implies the other，overestimating refers to a mental activity which need not express itself in praising or
favoring the person, and on the other hand one can praise sb. without ever overestimating the person.
关于＂抬举某人＂ 和 ＂对某人估计过高＂之间的差别。后者指的是项智力活动未必意味着抬举（估计过高的人），另一方面很可能抬举某人而不把那个人估计过高